# Running vba macro via python but can you add progress bar in python to measure vba procress?

Tags: python, progress-bar

I am currently running a VBA Macro using python so I can automate some of the processes, I also currently use tqdm to add a processbar to my other python code which is extremely useful.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to run macros and measure how long it will take and use the process bar to see what stage I am at as I have set it to run in the background? The code take between 5 - 6 hours to run so would be good to know how long I have left.

```
import xlwings as xw

def run_mac(file_path):
    
    try:
        xl = xw.App(visible=True, add_book=False)
        wb = xl_app.books.open(file_path)

        run_macro = wb.app.macro('lookupLoop.Open_Report')
        run_macro()

        wb.save()
        wb.close()

        xl.quit()

    except Exception as ex:
        template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
        error = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
        print(error)


run_mac(input('Excel path: '))
```

This is what I have for the file transfer:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know much about macros, but based on a previous question of yours I have come implemented a progress bar to provide information on what file has been transferred.

```
import os
import shutil
import time
import datetime
import tqdm

src = "C:/Users/eldri/OneDrive/Desktop/"
dst = "C:/Users/eldri/OneDrive/Desktop/output"
ext = input("[+] File format: ")  # "txt"
start = input("[+] Date start: ")  # "01/07/2020"
end = input("[+] Date end: ")  # "30/07/2020"


def dateRange(createdDate, startDate, endDate):
    """determines if date is in range"""
    createdDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(createdDate, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
    startDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(startDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
    endDate = datetime. datetime.strptime(endDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
    return startDate < createdDate < endDate


files = os.listdir(src)
numFiles = len(files)
pbar = tqdm.tqdm()
for filename, i in zip(files, tqdm.trange(numFiles-1)):
    print(filename)
    created = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(src + filename))
    if filename.endswith('.' + ext) and dateRange(created, start, end):
        shutil.copy(src + filename, dst)
        msg = "[+] File transferred " + filename + created
    else:
        msg = "[+] File not transferred " + filename + created
    pbar.set_postfix_str(msg)

print("[+] Transfer complete")
```

the progress bar shows `100%|██████████| 10/10 [00:50<00:00,  5.00s/it]` `10/10` is the number of files transferred, `[00:50<00:00,` has the format `[time taken<time remaining,` and `5.00s/it]` indicates how long it takes to copy one file.
All times are estimates based on the average time to copy a file.

Comment: This is absolutely amazing, thank you so much. I have just run the code, it works perfectly, I am reverse engineering it to work out what you did, sometimes I find it easier to work backwards. Can I ask, is the new bar generated because it is reading the file and then calculating the time? and copy time calculated by tdqm?

Comment: I got this error when i moved computer:
 pbar.set_postfix_str(msg)
AttributeError: 'tqdm' object has no attribute 'set_postfix_str'

Comment: The bar is generated for the iteration in trange, and the time calculated is the time taken to do one iteration multiplied by the number of iterations left to go - that's may understanding of this module anyway

Comment: The error maybe caused by the tqdm module installed, try to reinstall it, otherwise I'd ask about that on their git hub, sorry I can't be of more use

Comment: you are legendary uninstalling and installing again worked perfectly. Thank you so much

Comment: Sorry to ask another question but can a spinner be added to a process that is running? so like above that Macro process take about 5 hours to run and want to show that it is processing as show value is will be False. I have looked at spinners using progressbar but if you have an idea of what other modules I could use that would be amazing.

Comment: Do you mean use a spinner instead of a progress bar? If so please make a new question. You wont be able to use both a spinner and progress bar